# Why does Parse LiveQuery not always trigger update/create/enter event?

Tags: parse-server, livequery

I am trying to achieve a board that enables real-time editing for cooperating users. I am running a parse server using Sashido, where I have LiveQueries enabled for among other things 'Sticky'. For the frontend I have the following code:

```
const query = new Parse.Query(Sticky);
... some query constraints

this.subscription = await query.subscribe();

this.subscription.on('open', () => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: opened');
}

this.subscription.on('create', (sticky) => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: created');
}

this.subscription.on('update', (sticky) => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: updated');
}

this.subscription.on('enter', (sticky) => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: entered');
}

this.stickies = await query.find();
```

When I open my application in two different browser tabs, I get the 'SUBSCRIPTION: opened'. When I edit or create Sticky instances, I expect to get the corresponding events and see changes in the Sashido database.

However, I always see the changes in the database, but half of the times when I create or edit Sticky instances, I do not get the update/create/enter events. **Note: Sometimes they do get triggered**, but I have not found a sequence of events that leads to them being triggered or not, it seems to happen at random.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like some issue with your Parse Server setup. You should open a ticket in your hosting provider.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @FabioNapodano Yeah, I believe the issue was that our backend was hosted on multiple cores (not sure whether cores is the correct word) on Sashido. That messed up the registration of the livequeries, We switched back to running it on one core which solved the problem.

Comment: I solved by updating Parse Server to v.2.8.4